# Complex model structure and InvalidOperationException on CancelViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, model, invalidoperationexception, catel

I have a model architecture similar to this one in a viewmodel (skipping the implementation as it is not relevant):

```
public ObservableCollection<Filetype> Filetypes

[Model]
public Filetype Filetype

[ViewModelToModel("Filetype")]
public ObservableCollection<DocumentType> DocumentTypes

[Model]
public DocumentType DocumentType

public ObservableCollection<Library> Libraries

[Model]
[ViewModelToModel("DocumentType")]
public Library Library

[ViewModelToModel("Library")]
public ObservableCollection<ContentType> ContentTypes

[ViewModelToModel("DocumentType")]
[Model]
public ContentType ContentType
```

There is no mistake on this conception, everything that is marked `[Model]` **has** to be a model at one point. Of course, `Filetype`, `Library`, `DocumentType` and `ContentType` are all representing the selected value (in the view) of their respective collections.

My problem arises when I'm setting `ContentType`, then closing my window (during `DataWindow.OnClosing`). `InvalidOperationException: the collection has been modified`, inside `ViewModelBase.CancelViewModel`.

It is similar to [this reported bug](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-376), i.e `ContentType` is a property of `DocumentType` **and** a member of `Library.ContentTypes`, which I assume creates issues when cleaning all registered models.

Looking at the comments, I tried the solutions (setting `Model(SupportIEditableObject:=False)` to `DocumentType`, removing `[Model]` from ContentType and even all of this at once), without success.

**How can I keep this model structure in my viewmodel? Do I have to create another viewmodel for DocumentType?**

Comment: I think this is caused because you reset the collections (DocumentTypes / ContentTypes). You can always choose to map it manually.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to that in Catel. Does that mean I have to create a private variable `contentType` and such? In that case, `ContentType` won't be able to be a `[Model]`, and if so, would I have to map each of its properties the same way?

Comment: Yes, as you would need in any other fx.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's a catel issue, I love it so far and blame my errors on the youth of my MVVM experience :p